# SQL Case NOT NULL as value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return NOT NULL and NULL as the result of a CASE statement but I can't find the right way to do it

What I have below is incorrect and underlines the `NOT` keyword

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY d.cnumber DESC) AS RowNum,
    d.cnumber,
    d.firstname,
    d.lastname,
    d.current_email,
    d.updated_email,
    d.optedin,
    d.activated             
FROM    
    Customer d 
WHERE (d.optedin = 
           CASE WHEN @query = 'UNSUBMITTED' OR @query = 'SUBMITTED' 
                    THEN d.optedin
                WHEN @query = 'OPTEDIN' 
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END) AND
      (d.activated =
           CASE WHEN @query = 'OPTEDIN' OR @query = 'OPTEDOUT' 
                    THEN d.activated 
                WHEN @query = 'UNSUBMITTED' 
                    THEN NULL 
                ELSE NOT NULL END)
```

`activated` is a nullable datetime field. `@query` is a varchar parameter

Comment: You can't say = NULL *or* = NOT NULL.

Comment: Your CASE statement needs to RETURN a value - A CASE statement is not a WHERE clause which CHECKS a value.  Think about what you want to return and want to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `case` in a `where` clause is usually an indication you've taken the wrong path. I believe that you'll find you can solve this with more standard logic:

```
WHERE (@query in ( 'UNSUBMITTED', 'SUBMITTED') 
         OR (@query = 'OPTEDIN' AND d.optedin = 1)
         OR d.optedin = 0)
       AND
      (@query in ('OPTEDIN', 'OPTEDOUT')
         OR (@query = 'UNSUBMITTED' AND d.activated IS NULL)
         OR  d.activated IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: That's the one! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you modify the condition for d.activated to this:

```
AND (@query = 'UNSUBMITTED' AND d.activated IS NULL OR @query <> 'UNSUBMITTED' AND d.activated IS NOT NULL)
```

Please note that you do not need to specifically test for this condition:

```
CASE WHEN @query = 'OPTEDIN' OR @query = 'OPTEDOUT' 
                THEN d.activated
```

As it will be covered by `OR d.activated IS NOT NULL` in the condition that I have proposed

BTW, for d.optedin you can use the similar:

```
(@query = 'OPTEDIN' AND d.optedin = 1 OR @query <> 'OPTEDIN' AND d.optedin = 0)
```

Comment: "d.activated IS NULL OR d.activated IS NOT NULL" will never filter out anything - it is all possible results. Maybe you are missing brackets

Comment: Almost works, but for UNSUBMITTED it also returns rows that have a value in the `activated` column

Comment: @simo.379209 Yeah I assumed the missing brackets.

Comment: @simo.379209: No, I am not missing brackets. If you wish you can bracket the AND condition, but it will be useless: `AND` is executed first, and then `OR`. It is called [operator precedence] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Comment: @JamesHay: thanks for the tip about UNSUBMITTED . I have updated the answer

Comment: I marked Allens because that one makes the most sense to me and works as I expect. But I +1'd you, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ELSE NOT NULL
```

is too vague.  SQL Server does not know what to return.  You have to specify a value that is the same datatype as d.activated.

Comment: Well I want to return all of the rows that don't have a NULL value in that column, just like saying `WHERE d.activated IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @James Then replace `NOT NULL` with `d.activated`. You'll also need to replace the other spot where you compare it to `NULL` with something else that is also comparable as a datetime (like `DATEADD(DAY,1,d.Activated)`).